# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_columns'

Tags: python, odoo

I am writing a module in OpenERP that would inherit from the Accounts module. Below is my simplified code

```
from osv import fields, osv
import decimal_precision as dp

class account_molly(osv.osv):

    def __computeOB(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):
        res = []
        return 0

    def __computeCB(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):
        res = []
        return 0

    _name = "account.molly"
    _description = "This is Molly Special Account View"
    _inherit = "account.account"
    _columns = {
        'opening_balance': fields.function(__computeOB, digits_compute=dp.get_precision('Account'), method=True, string='Opening Balance'),
        'end_balance': fields.function(__computeCB, digits_compute=dp.get_precision('Account'), method=True, string='End Balance'),
    }   

account_molly()

# vim:expandtab:smartindent:tabstop=4:softtabstop=4:shiftwidth=4:
```

When I try to install the module, I get

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_columns'
```

Please what could be the problem

Comment: when you try to import or install?

Comment: According to the OpenERP [documentation](http://doc.openerp.com/v6.0/developer/2_5_Objects_Fields_Methods/object_attributes.html) you need to have a `_name=name.of.the.object` property.

Comment: Even with the name property, It was still giving me the same error. I just removed it so that it would like the main python file in sale_crm module

Comment: What is the line of code you're actually using to instantiate the `account_molly` object?

Comment: This is what I have in my init.py file
<pre><code>import account_molly</code></pre>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please check the dependency of the module you have created. In the **openerp**.py file, in the dependency list if 'account' is not added, please add it. If this didnt solve your problem please provide the error log

Answer (score -1):

does this solve the problem?

```
class account_molly(osv):
    ...
```

you seem to mix module and class and class attribute

Comment: I have never seen anything like this before on any OpenERP documentation. Anyway I tried it and this is the error I got TypeError: Error when calling the metaclass bases
    module.__init__() takes at most 2 arguments (3 given)