# How to debug Assertion error in openerp 7

Tags: python, odoo

After googling a lot i come to stackoverflow how to debug this error

i am getting this error when i am trying to create the new field from the web client

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_columns'

Comment: first you should double check the sanity of your module declaration. Second: google for """AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_columns'". The web is plenty of such an error. Then if you still have the problem: you MUST report the full traceback and sample of your code in order to allow people to understand what's going on.

Comment: oh, look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10565288/attributeerror-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-columns

Answer (score 0):

This error usually arise when you don't provide correct dependency for your module. Please check whether you have given correct dependency in your `__openerp__.py` file

Comment: Well its a fresh install on ubuntu and i am getting this error only on while creating a new field from the webclient!!